# Speech to Text conversion in Android -mic control

Tags: java, android

I wrote a code that converts audio to text, but I have a problem
microphone control,
When you press the icon to speak, it closes quickly in case I don't speak quickly
And when you stop talking it turns off automatically.
I want the microphone to stay on even after I stop talking.
How do I control the opening and closing of the microphone?

This is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    imageButton=findViewById(R.id.button);
    editText=findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},1);
    }
    speechRecognizer=SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
     final Intent speechRecognizerIntent= new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
     imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             if (count==0)
             {
                 imageButton.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_mic_24));

                 //startlistening
                 speechRecognizer.startListening(speechRecognizerIntent);
                 count=1;


             }
             else
                 {
                     imageButton.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_mic_off_24));
                     //stop listening
                     speechRecognizer.stopListening();
                     count=0;

                 }
         }
     });


     speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
         @Override
         public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

         }

         @Override
         public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onEndOfSpeech() {
            /* if (speechRecognizer != null) {
                 speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);
             }*/

         }

         @Override
         public void onError(int error) {
         }

         @Override
         public void onResults(Bundle results) {

             ArrayList<String> data = results.getStringArrayList(speechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
             editText.setText(data.get(0));

         }

         @Override
         public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

         }
     });
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode==1)
    {
        if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you check the logs? What error did you get?

Comment: I didn't encounter an error in the code, but I want a way to control the mic through the code.